# Pythonic way to iterate through content-range during request get call

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

The GET rest api returns

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< rlogid: t6elbbolst2%3F%3Ckuv%60ng%60jnvv7*6565%3B37-17d3a004c7d-0x233d
< content-range: nodes 1-397/397
< x-ebay-request-id: 17d3a004-c7e0-a4cc-d414-b222ff7438ae!Ginger.LIST FOLDER.GET!lvsfidelius1-5002861.stratus.lvs.ebay.com!r1fidelius1[]
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 173
< date: Fri, 19 Nov 2021 21:00:37 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 11
< server: ebay server
```

I am using `request` module. Right now I have to make two calls

1. The first call so that I get the `total` from `content-range`
2. The second call to call the api by passing total to get everything

I am using the while loop

```
   def get_children(self, size=500):
        while True:
            url = "{}/list?size={}".format(
                self.endpoint, size)

            result = requests.get(url, verify=False)
            result.raise_for_status()

            if 'content-range' in result.headers:
                crange = result.headers['content-range']
                size = int(
                    re.match(ur'^nodes \d+-(\d+)\/(\d+)$', crange).group(1))
                total = int(
                    re.match(ur'^nodes \d+-(\d+)\/(\d+)$', crange).group(2))
                if size < total:
                    size = total
                else:
                    break
        return result.json()
```

I feel there is a better way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: you didn't show URL for this API so we can't say if there is no better method.

Comment: if you can get all in second requests then maybe in first you can use size `1` to send less data. OR maybe it can use requests `OPTIONS` or `HEAD` instead `GET` to get only headers.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Right now the size is set significantly high to complete this request in a single call. I guess the solution that I have isn't so bad.